# can we use HANDLE from winnt in a qt application?

Tags: c++, qt

i want use the HANDLE(a windows data type in winnt.h, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) thing for my thread in my qt program? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you really need this. Perhaps [QThread::currentThreadId()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qthread.html#currentThreadId) is enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can use the `HANDLE` data type in your Qt app. It will, however, make the app non-portable.